# How can I pin a webapp to my GNOME 3.0 desktop?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

I'm running Arch Linux with the gnome-unstable desktop environment. I remember pinning websites to the taskbar in Windows 7, and was wondering how I might do that in Linux.

Basically, I want a single-site browser that will appear in my Applications list with the icon from the site.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple. The menu items are populated from the .desktop entries in `/usr/share/applications" and "$HOME/.local/share` locations.. You can create custom `.desktop` files and put them in one of these locations. That will start showing up in Gnome desktop with other applications..

For more information on how to create .desktop files, have a look at this:

> http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en